# Even/Odd Numbers in Arm

Tags: arm

I am trying to write an ARM program that counts the number of odd numbers written in a .txt file and sums the amount of even numbers.

I understand that the least significant binary digit(Z Bit) signifies whether a number is odd or even.

My question is which instruction(s) can I use to get this done, and also how can I create an "if" statement that compares the values?

Basically what I want to do is compare the number using something like:

```
@condition "if number from file is even"
add r4,r1,r4
@condition "if number from file is odd"
add r5,r5,#1
```

I just need a little help with the syntax for the conditions

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Z bit is a condition code bit which is true if the value the conditions codes were set from is "Zero".  You can set the condition codes with (for example):

```
tst r1,#1
```

Then the Z bit will be set if the number is even, and clear if it is odd.  You can then use conditional execution to control the additions:

```
addeq r4,r1,r4
addne r5,r5,#1
```